# What is the difference between the standard error of a regression coefficient in R and the standard deviation of the coefficient estimate?

Tags: r, regression

In R, the output for a `lm` linear regression model shows the "standard error":

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -17.5791     6.7584  -2.601   0.0123 *  
beta_1       3.9324      0.4155   9.464 1.49e-12 ***
---
```

If my estimtate of $\beta_1$ is $\hat{\beta_1}= (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$, what is the difference between the reported `Std. Error` vs. $\sqrt{\text{Var}\left(\hat{\beta_1}\right)}$?

Comment: $\hat{\beta}_1$ is a statistic, i.e. it is a function of the data so it is fixed - if you're a frequentist. Therefore $\text{var}(\hat{\beta_1}) = 0$. You can create a little variable like $S_n$ to refer to the approximation to the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the least squares slope estimator.

Comment: @AdamO I don't know anyone, "frequentist" or otherwise, who would seriously contend that $\operatorname{Var}(\hat \beta_1) = 0,$ because that imposes a ludicrous meaning on the variance.  Just as almost anyone would tell you the variance of a fair coin flip is $1/4$ even after collecting some data, they will understand this variance to be an *estimate* of the variance of the statistic.

Comment: @AdamO I get the stance that you calculate the value of $\hat\beta_1$ as a number and that a number has a variance of zero, but your phrasing seems to dismiss the idea of a sampling distribution.

Comment: @whuber haha well trivialities aside, the question asks, "what's the difference" between the expressions. Surely one could say, there is none, but of course that's not always the case. There are several considerations: are the residuals normal? Are they independent? What specific expression for the variance of the beta-hat estimator is considered? So, as-is, there's no way to answer this without being wrong in a few scenarios.